# Reactjs pseudo element behind element in sliding animation

Tags: css, reactjs, pseudo-element

I have this button group, with the desired effect being a red background and white text when the corresponding button is active.

React component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [timeline, setTimeline] = useState(12);
  return (
      <div className="multi-button-group">
        <button
          className={timeline === 6 ? "active" : ""}
          onClick={() => setTimeline(6)}
        >
          6 months
        </button>
        <button
          className={timeline === 12 ? "active" : ""}
          onClick={() => setTimeline(12)}
        >
          12 months
        </button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.multi-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0%;
  background: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.multi-button-group button:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.multi-button-group button:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: none;
}

.multi-button-group button:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.multi-button-group button:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

.multi-button-group button.active {
  color: white;
}

.multi-button-group button.active:first-child ~ button::after{
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.multi-button-group button.active:nth-child(2) ~ button::after{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Problem:
When I click on 6 months, the ::after is in the correct position but not showing up
[image]

When I click on 12 months, the ::after is in the wrong position

[image]

One of the things I tried is to tweak the z-index of the ::after but I still could not get the desired effect.

I have not decided to set the default timeline as 6 or 12 months yet, and am trying to write the CSS in such a way that both options will work.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the styles in the following way to make it work as described

There is also a link to sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-williamson-j666qv

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.multi-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0%;
  background: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.multi-button-group button:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.multi-button-group button:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: none;
}

.multi-button-group button:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.multi-button-group button::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  left: 0;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.multi-button-group button.active {
  color: white;
}

.multi-button-group button.active::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.multi-button-group button:not(.active):last-child:after {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.multi-button-group button:not(.active):first-child:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the answer itself, an external snippet is fine as an additional resource, but it shouldn't be the only place we can see your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer and added the modified styles